# Curl sends but Lambda (Netlify function) forbidden

Tags: mailgun

I'm developing a function on Netlify to process a contact form using MailGun as the email sender (via API)

I tested the service by sending from my localhost using curl - fine. But when I invoke the function (again on the localhost) I receive a "forbidden" error. In the function, I've received the same error with and without /messages on the end or the url.

Is my error in the code or does MailGun respond differently to the two different cases - I am using another email provider so I don't have MX records pointing to MailGun.

Here's the curl

```
curl -s --user 'api:exampleofverylongsecretkey' https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com/messages 
-F from='Excited User <mailgun@mg.example.com>' 
-F to=boreduser@otherexample.com 
-F subject='Hello' 
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

Here is the function paired down to basics with hard-coded everything just to get mailgun working

````
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

exports.handler = async (event) => 
{
   const mg = mailgun({
       apiKey: "key-exampleofverylongsecretkey", 
       domain: "mg.example.com",
       url: "https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.example.com"
   });

   const data = {
       from: 'Name <mailgun@mg.example.com>',
       to: 'bored@otherexample.com',
       subject: 'Worldish',
       text: 'Hello W',
       html: 'HTML'
       };

   return mg.messages().send(data).then(() => ({
       statusCode: 200,
       body: "Your message was sent successfully! We'll be in touch."
   })).catch(error => ({
       statusCode: 422,
       body: `Error: ${error}`
   }));
} ``` 

ps - I've tried it with 'key-exampleofsecretcode' and 'exampleofsecretcode' and with and without the url and with the url with and without /messages - same result for all
````

Answer (score 0):

Resolved -

First sent successfully from hardcoded sandbox details, then live details - failing when using process.env

Re-installed dotenv - now all working